# Adding tags for questions tagged inconsistently (Placeholder)

Tags: app, placeholder

I'm adding a new tag to all questions that satisfy certain rules, to keep tagging more consistent.

See [*Which tag(s) to use for Python typing questions*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347712/which-tags-to-use-for-python-typing-questions) for details.